# Django filter queryset in Annotation

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-orm

I have the following `models`.

```
1. City
2. Picture
3. Video
```

I want to get the counts of `Picture` and `Video` for every city using `annotate`. The only problem I am facing is I do not know a way how to filter on annotated object.

```
cities = City.objects.filter(pro=pro).annotate(
        img_count=Count('city_pictures', distinct=True),
        video_count=Count('city_videos', distinct=True)).order_by('-img_count').values('name', 'img_count', 'video_count')
```

### Problem

Right now, I can not filter images which are `verified`

### Patch Solution

`cities = City.objects.default().filter(pro=pro)`

```
for city in cities:
    city.image_count = Picture.objects.filter(verified=True).count()
    city.video_count = Vidoe.objects.filter(verified=True).count()
```

But that would make additional queries into the database. I need way by which I can make minimum db queries and achieve what I am looking for.

Thanks.

Comment: What django version are you using?

Comment: Django 1.5, Python2.7

Answer (score 0):

You should use here aggregate_if package ([link](https://github.com/henriquebastos/django-aggregate-if)).

It contains `Count`, `Min`, `Max`, etc implementations with `only` parameter which you can use to pass required `Q` objects.

Your final code should look like this:

```
from aggregate_if import Count  # don't forget to import it from here!

cities = City.objects.filter(pro=pro).annotate(
        img_count=Count('city_pictures', distinct=True, only=Q(city_pictures__verified=True)),
        video_count=Count('city_videos', distinct=True, only=Q(city_videos__verified=True))).order_by('-img_count').values('name', 'img_count', 'video_count')
```